# Check if cassandra materialized view reflects the data up to a point

Tags: cassandra

I would like to be able to determine if a materialized view (being eventual consistent) is reflecting all the data up to a point.

Perfectly it would be an API that I call and say wait until all the data before this call is reflected.

But I am open for any tricky idea that includes pulling if needed.

Answer (score 6):

There is currentely no way to know that for sure. What's worse, nothing in the Cassandra implementation guarantees that 1) all updates to a base table will make it to the view, or 2) there will be no ghost records in the view.

To deal with 1), you can turn on the `cassandra.mv_enable_coordinator_batchlog` option (turned off by default, due to serious performance implications). This will ensure a base replica remembers the view update in a system table and will retry it until it can reach the view replica.

There is currentely no way to deal with 2), which can happen if a view replica loses an update containing a tombstone or if the base replica is lost after it having update the view.